# Autodim does not un-dim when I start using the computer again

Tags: 11.10, power-management, hibernate, macbook

On my MacBook 2,1 with Ubuntu 11.10, whenever I leave the computer alone for five minutes, it blacks out and wont respond to any keypresses or even the power button.

UPDATE: It was the autodim feature that didn't un-dim itself after starting to use the computer again. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a very similar issue (couldn't resume from suspend). It's apparently a recognized bug in the 3.0 kernel.  I updated to 12.04 (alpha 2), which uses kernel version 3.2, and it fixed the problem.  3.0 is also known for being inefficient power-wise.  I gained more than an hour of battery life from moving up to 3.2.

Comment: I did to that. The resume problem is gone, but I now have a whole slew of new problems.

Also, no increase in battery life after the update.

Comment: Hi Peter.  I'm sorry to hear that.  Unless you had serious battery life degradation though, you wouldn't see any improvements.  You might want to try `laptop-mode-tools` once you get your other problems fixed.  Some of them might be caused by any modifications you made to get your MacBook to work with earlier versions of Ubuntu.